# How do I get a variable input to print?

Tags: python-3.x, input, printing

I'm trying to get an input to print for a class assignment.

```
# Program Name: BadDate.py 
# Function:     This program determines if a date entered by the user is valid.  
# Input:        Interactive
# Output:       Valid date is printed or user is alerted that an invalid date was entered.

validDate = True
MIN_YEAR = 0
MIN_MONTH = 1
MAX_MONTH = 12
MIN_DAY = 1
MAX_DAY = 31

month = float (input("Enter Month "))
day = float (input("Enter Day "))
year = float (input("Enter Year "))


# Get the month, then the day, then the year
# housekeeping()

# Check to be sure date is valid

if int(year) <= MIN_YEAR: # invalid year
    validDate = False
elif int(month) < MIN_MONTH or int(month) > MAX_MONTH: # invalid month
    validDate = False
elif int(day) < MIN_DAY or int(day) > MAX_DAY: # invalid day
    validDate = False

# Test to see if date is valid and output date and whether it is valid or not
if validDate == True:
    print(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year) " is a valid date") 
else:
    print(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year) " is an invalid date")

# endOfJob()
```

It's giving me a syntax error when it gets to the date. I need the statements to print the dates that get entered by the user. Thank you.

Comment: You are missing a `+` sign between the `str(year)` and `" is a ...date"`. It should be `str(year) + " is a ...date"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the error given, you might be able to spot it.
Now, as a new user, it might seem challenging to decode those errors and where they come from. It would've been helpful for you to include the `SyntaxError` stack trace, so we could help show you where the issue is faster.

Anyways, you were just missing 2 simple concatenation/plus operators (`+`) in the calls to the print function, so here's the fixed code:

```
# Program Name: BadDate.py 
# Function:     This program determines if a date entered by the user is valid.  
# Input:        Interactive
# Output:       Valid date is printed or user is alerted that an invalid date was entered.

validDate = True
MIN_YEAR = 0
MIN_MONTH = 1
MAX_MONTH = 12
MIN_DAY = 1
MAX_DAY = 31

month = float (input("Enter Month "))
day = float (input("Enter Day "))
year = float (input("Enter Year "))


# Get the month, then the day, then the year
# housekeeping()

# Check to be sure date is valid

if int(year) <= MIN_YEAR: # invalid year
    validDate = False
elif int(month) < MIN_MONTH or int(month) > MAX_MONTH: # invalid month
    validDate = False
elif int(day) < MIN_DAY or int(day) > MAX_DAY: # invalid day
    validDate = False

# Test to see if date is valid and output date and whether it is valid or not
if validDate == True:
    print(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year) + " is a valid date") 
else:
    print(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year) + " is an invalid date")

# endOfJob()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all these into one condition:

```
month = int(input("Enter Month "))
day = int (input("Enter Day "))
year = int (input("Enter Year "))
if 1<=day<=31 and year>0 and 1<=month<=12:
    print(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year)+ " is a valid date") 
else:
    print(str(month)+'/'+str(day)+'/'+str(year) +" is an invalid date")
```

Although as given, it means putting something like `Feb 30 02` will be considered valid etc

Answer (score 0):

Was able to condense a bit. Enjoy!

```
year = int(input("Enter a year: "))
month = int(input("Enter a month: "))
day = int(input("Enter a day: "))

date = "/".join([str(month),str(day),str(year)])

if validDate == True:
print(date," is a valid date.")
else:
print(date," is an invalid date.")
```